# Flutter Detect Notification Tray Pulldown

Tags: flutter, detect, system-tray

I'm trying to implement a feature based on the background/foreground status of a Flutter app.

Does anyone know of a way to detect if the notification/system try on a device is pulled down over the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SOF

You can detect this using special permission in Android (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#EXPAND_STATUS_BAR).

But you need native code to run in Flutter.

There is a similar (almost) package out there, you may fork it:
https://pub.dev/packages/notification_shade

Comment: Ok, great. I'll add the permission and look into using a MethodChannel or Activity binding to test that out. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Did it work ? I am looking for notification tray pulldown event , can you add more details about how can i do that?